# Getting the VC dialog editor to recognise a dialog class in a namespace

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, dialog

I'm trying to hook up a dialog class in a namespace to a template in a way that will allow me to use the editors class/method wizard features to add message handlers to the dialog and its controls.

As soon as I add the namespace and save/reload trying to use Class wizard in the dialog editor prompts me to create a new dialog class. Has anyone had experience of this? I'm using 2010. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible. It was reported as a bug.

One of the cheesy solutions:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/543019/class-wizard-and-class-view-does-not-detect-namespaces-changes-in-configurations